# For what $x$ is $x^2- |x-2| - 6 > 0$ satisfied?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For what range of values of $x$ is the following modulus inequality satisfied:

$x^2- |x-2| - 6 > 0$

EDIT: I broke the problem into two parts. First case is where $x<2$. , and the second case is where $x \ge 2$

The answer that I am getting is

$x<\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{2}$ for $x<2$

and

$x\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$ for $x \ge 2$

However the answer in the book is different. I am getting the correct answer for the first case, but for the second case the answer is $x\ge 2$.

Comment: Take cases, for $x \gt 2$ and $x \le 2$, and remove the modulus sign. You will get two quadratics, which you analyse separately
Note: Remember that for each quadratic, the range of x is not $\mathbb R$

Comment: @mathlover I just edited my query. Dhanvi I am getting an incorrect answer using this approach.

Comment: @Sakshi agarwal..you have to take the intersection of ${x\in \mathbb R:x≧2}$ and ${x\in\mathbb R: x≧(1+√17)/2}$

Comment: @mathlover I am getting the same answer. But the book answer is different

Comment: @Sakshi agarwal..show your calculations to update your question. However the approach looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: consider $x = 2, < 2, > 2$.